# Bazel build part of third party library as static library with headers

Tags: c++, bazel, xla-compiler

I'm trying to build a subset of a third-party C++ library. I want as output a static library (`.lo` probably), and the headers of the specified targets. I'm not adding any of my own source files at this stage. How do I do this?

I will use this to compile a single dynamic (`.so`) library with some wrapper code.

The library I'm building is XLA but a generic solution is welcome. I've tried various iterations on this

```
cc_library(
    name = "my_xla",
    srcs = [],
    deps = [
        "@xla//xla/client:xla_builder,
        "@com_google_absl//absl/strings:str_format",
        "@tsl//tsl/platform:logging",
        "@tsl//tsl/platform:platform_port",
    ],
    hdrs = [
        "@xla//xla/client:xla_builder",
    ],
    alwayslink = True,
)
```

and it builds "successfully", but I'm not getting a `.a` or `.lo` in my bazel-bin dir, or a list of headers. Here's my `WORKSPACE`

```
local_repository(
  name = "xla",
  path = "xla",
)

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

load("@xla//:workspace4.bzl", "xla_workspace4")
xla_workspace4()

load("@xla//:workspace3.bzl", "xla_workspace3")
xla_workspace3()

load("@xla//:workspace2.bzl", "xla_workspace2")
xla_workspace2()

load("@xla//:workspace1.bzl", "xla_workspace1")
xla_workspace1()

load("@xla//:workspace0.bzl", "xla_workspace0")
xla_workspace0()
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon i'm building on mac M1 and ubuntu, to run on mac m1 and ubuntu

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon i'd be more than happy with just an ubuntu solution

Comment: Dan this is for building a C++ library. Why do you think it's not relevant to C++?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon The .lo and .so files should have given you a clue.

Comment: Hi @[stackoverblown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13202601/stackoverblown) please do not delete your comment to leave room for context such that my reply won’t be misunderstood. I’ll try to say this in the most respectful manner possible so don’t find it offensive. *”If you knew the history, development and evolution of UNIX, you would not have made that comment”*.

Comment: Try using `linkstatic`.  See https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_library.linkstatic as well as https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/1920

Comment: @Den-Jason thanks for those, they explain exactly the problem I have (almost down to the library). Looks like I'll need to wait and persuade the XLA team to update their bazel version

Answer (score -1):

To build a subset of a third-party C++ library like XLA as a static library with headers using Bazel, you need to properly define your BUILD file and ensure that the necessary targets are included. also,
Regarding the absence of the .a or .lo file in your bazel-bin directory, it's possible that Bazel is not actually building the library because it's empty due to having no source files. Since you mentioned you want to compile a dynamic library with some wrapper code, you'll need to add some source files to your my_xla target, even if they're just empty placeholder files.

```
cc_library(
    name = "my_xla",
    hdrs = glob(["path/to/xla/client/*.h"]),  ### Adjust the path
    srcs = ["path/to/emptyfile.cc"],  ### Replace Placeholder source file
    deps = [
        "@xla//xla/client:xla_builder",
        "@com_google_absl//absl/strings:str_format",
        "@tsl//tsl/platform:logging",
        "@tsl//tsl/platform:platform_port",
    ],
)
```

Comment: thanks but I want two separate build steps - first building a static library with headers, then build a dynamic library on top of that. That separation is crucial to the question